# Subtracting hours

Tags: cognito-forms

Trying to subtract two times.  I have a time input box called Start Time and a time input box called End Time.  Using a calculated field set to time `=(EndTime-StartTime).TotalHours`, I've tried `.Hours` as well.  No matter how I write the calculation get the error "The expected type of this field is 'DateTime'"

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms, I was able to reproduce this issue in our testing environment when the Calculation Type was set to 'Time'. In the settings for the Calculation Field try setting the Type to 'Number'. You are looking for a number value from the subtraction of the two times. You can continue to use either .Hours or .TotalHours.

[image]

Comment: Cognito Forms does have a duration, called [TimeSpan](http://help.cognitoapps.com/understanding-calculations-timespan-functions), which is the type returned by the calculation (StartTime - EndTime).  Time is a point in time on no specific day, like 3:00 PM, whereas TimeSpan represents a time interval, like 3 hours and 5 minutes.  The issue in this case was the expected type of the calculation did not match the type returned by the expression.